# Select2 AJAX POST request not working with laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am using the select2 jQuery plugin to search for an item using POST request.
I am stuck with laravel getting a 301 (Moved Permanently) error.

The snippet of my code is shown below where I try to search for a team and select it. Unfortunately, the code works on my localhost server and not the actual production server.

```
 $("#team_assign_select").select2({

        delay: 250,
        ajax: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/teams/search/',

            dataType: 'json',

            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },

            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
                    team_name: params.term // search term
                };
            },  
            cache: true
        },

        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Select team',
        width: 400,
       
        minimumInputLength: 0

    });
```

Please I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm answering my own question.
The solution is ridiculously simple.

Make sure the URL does not end with a `/` if you want to use a POST request.

That is to say, I modified the ajax request object from this:

```
ajax: {
       ...
       url: '/teams/search/',
       ...
}
```

into this:

```
ajax: {
     ...
     url: '/teams/search',
     ...
}
```

Again, notice there is no ending ***forward slash*** ('`/`') at the end of the new ajax request object.

Below is the rectified code snippet to work with the Ajax `POST` request.

```
// Select the team to assign the job to when adding a job
$("#team_assign_select").select2({

    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/teams/search',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        dataType: 'json',

        data: function(params) {
            var query = {
                team_name: (params.term == undefined) ? '' : params.term,
                _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
            return query;
        },
    },
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'Select team',
    width: 400,
    processResults: function(data) {
        console.log('Processing data');
        // Transforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
        return {
            results: data.items
        };
    },
    minimumInputLength: 0

});
```